# Why I am not getting error with ref keyword

Tags: c#, asp.net, ref, out

According to definition, `ref` keyword must be initialized before passing. while `out` parameters must be initialized before returning from the function.

Below is my snippet.

```
   public void TestRef(ref string n)
    {

    }

    public void TestOut(out string n)
    {

        n = "Hello"; //if I don't initialize, I gets compile time error. & That's right.

    }
```

Now while calling the methods.

```
string name;
TestOut(out name);//fine
TestRef(ref name) // why not throwing error.
```

> In the above calls when trying to call TestRef() I have not initialized name parameter. But as per my understanding ref parameter must be initialized before passing.

It builds & run with no errors.

Comment: `name` has been initialised by the call to `TestOut`.

Comment: Try to execute `TestRef(ref name)` before `TestOut(out name)` - you will get a compiler error.

Comment: @Lee. You're right. I got the point. Silly mistake. Thanks

Comment: @ZoharPeled. Yes. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TestOut` guarantees that `name` variable will be initialized when method will finish execution

See [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) keyword

> Although variables passed as out arguments do not have to be
>   initialized before being passed, the called method is required to
>   assign a value before the method returns

and [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

> An argument that is passed to a ref parameter must be initialized
>   before it is passed. This differs from out parameters, whose arguments
>   do not have to be explicitly initialized before they are passed. For
>   more information, see out.

Reorder the method calls and you will see the behavior you expect.

Comment: Good to see that you added explanation. It will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Calling the `TestOut` method first guarantees the initialization of the `name` variable. 
Reorder the method calls and you will see the behavior you expect.

Answer (score 0):

comment out the line 
TestOut(out name);//fineTestOut(out name);//fine
You will get error for the following lines
string name;
TestRef(ref name) // why not throwing error.